# I am deploying the interface with flask, the content of the interface is a deep learning model, I would like to ask how to achieve hot deployment?

Tags: tensorflow

I am deploying the interface with flask, the content of the interface is a deep learning model, I would like to ask how to achieve hot deployment? (ie, deploying a new model without interrupting the service)

I have already seen the documentation of the flask, it seems that there are no similar parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use different docker containers to deploy the app and one to store the model that your flask app calls.

This allows for separation of concerns, your flask app should be exposed to some generic api e.g. (get_model_inference()) that calls the model service.